# How to convert Dataset string type to Row type?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've below dataset of `String` type:

```
op.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String call(String value) throws Exception {

        return value;
    }

}, Encoders.STRING()).show();
```

My First doubt is how can I convert this above `String type Dataset` to `Row type Dataset` ?

Second, In same `Dataset of String type`, How can I get specific field in string separated by commas in Dataset ?

Comment: The above dataset is of type Row, a column of it will be of type String. I can't understand the question. if you like I can answer in Scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `toDF()` to convert a Dataset to a Dataframe [ aka Dataset[Row] ]

here is an example

```
  String[] l = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
  List<String> data = Arrays.asList(l);
  Dataset<String> ds = spark.createDataset(data, Encoders.STRING());
  Dataset<Row> df = ds.toDF();
  df.show();
```

For splitting the string column to a multiple columns , use a map function with a regex split method and return a tuple of the required split columns